# scrollsToTop and multiple scrollViews on-screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm currently working on an iPad app that should feature two `UITableViews` side-by-side (unfortunately, they can't be combined into a single one for some specific reasons).

As far as I know, `scrollsToTop` won't work properly for both of them, since only one `scrollView` should have this property enabled at a time. The thing, the app could really use this feature for both `tableViews`, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Is there any workaround that would allow me to have `scrollsToTop` enabled and working for both of them? Or maybe disabling it on both and then listening for touches on the status bar so the app can determine above which `tableView` they happen and scroll as appropriately? Or any other clever solutions?

**Edit:** `tableViews` shouldn't scroll up together. Each should scroll only if the tap on the status bar is right above them (just like if we had two iPhones side by side, for the lack of a better example).

Answer (score 1):

If you have many scrollviews this category is really useful.

```
-[UIScrollView makeOnlyThisScrollViewScrollToTopOnStatusBarTap];
```

https://gist.github.com/hfossli/6776203

It basically sets scrollsToTop to `NO` on all other scrollViews than the one you are specifying + taking care of the default value.

Answer (score 0):

There's a scroll view delegate method `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:`. Implement the method on one table view and in the method body tell the other one to also scroll to the top (probably with `setContentOffset:animated:`).

Comment: Thanks for the input, Nevan. The thing is, I would like them to scroll separately. I guess I hadn't really made this clear, so I've edited the question to reflect that.